# Trapeze shadow with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am wondering, is there a way to create shadow linke on the images below (possibly using pseudo class?)

[image]

The red bit behind grey box meant to be shadow with trapeze shape and no blur.

Now idea if its possible?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Just wondering what kind of light can make that shadow realistically. Cool effect.

Comment: Have a look at my answer if you need more let me know.

Answer (score 3):

## [DEMO 1:](http://jsfiddle.net/jsjubayd/)

HTML:

```
<figure></figure>
```

CSS:

```
   figure{
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        margin:50px auto;
        background:#ccc;
        position:relative;
        box-shadow: 0 14px 0 -10px red;
    }
    figure:before, figure:after{
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        top: 2px;
        width:0;
        height:0;
    }

    figure:before{
        left: -5px;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
        border-top: 77px solid red;
    }

    figure:after{
        right: -5px;
        border-left: 0px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 77px solid red;
    }
```

[image]

## [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jsjubayd/3/)

```
figure{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background:#ccc;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 0 -10px red;
}
figure:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800) rotateX(-40deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case of using CSS3 features, you could create a trapeze by applying a [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) on a pseudo-element and position that behind the box as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/xigozu/2/edit)**

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;        /* Optional */
    /* height: 150px; */ /* Optional */
    position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;

  top: -3%; bottom: -12%; left: 0; right: 0;
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Therefore dimensions of the shadow box would be relative to the box. However it is not supported in IE 9 and below.